# ! Too many }'s error when using beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, framed

**The error that appear is**

```
" [] 
! Too many }'s.

\endframe ->\egroup 

                    \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
l.45     \end{frame}"
```

**I do dont know where is the error.**

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}}

\begin{document}    

Se considera tomar parametros economicos sugeridos $q_1+q_2 =1$, (Representa un incremento en la productividad de un 10\% si fuerza de capital e inversión aumentan un 10 \%).

Los otros parametros son tomados de esta forma, para generar un foco estable interior.
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Equilibrios & Valores                           & Tipo      & $(n_+,n_-)$ \\ \hline
$E_1$ & $(0,0,0)$                               & Atractor  & $(0,3)$\\
$E_2$ & $(0,k_1,0)$                                 & Silla     & $(2,1)$\\
$E_3$ & $(0,k_2,0)$                                 & Silla     & $(1,2$)\\
$E_4$ & $(\frac{-\rho\tau^2-k_1\rho\tau\phi \Omega-k_2\rho\tau\phi \Omega- k_1 k_2\rho\phi^2\omega^2}{k_1k_2\phi^2\Omega^3},-\frac{\tau}{\phi\Omega},0)$        & Inestable     & $(3,0)$\\
$E_5$ & $(3.698.94, 7272.73, 672.53)$                               & Atractor & $(0,3)$\\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a `\begin{frame}`

Comment: as the error shows you have `\end{frame}` which is closing a group that never started,  you need `\begin{frame}` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle  , Would you like to give an answer?

Comment: @DaiBowen was first:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is missing a `\begin{frame}` and thus throwing an error when it meets an `\end{frame}` which attempts to close a frame environment which was never opened.

Adding `\begin{frame}` just after `\begin{document}` will enable the code to compile.

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
Se considera tomar parametros economicos sugeridos $q_1+q_2 =1$, (Representa un incremento en la productividad de un 10\% si fuerza de capital e inversión aumentan un 10 \%).

Los otros parametros son tomados de esta forma, para generar un foco estable interior.
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Equilibrios & Valores                           & Tipo      & $(n_+,n_-)$ \\ \hline
$E_1$ & $(0,0,0)$                               & Atractor  & $(0,3)$\\
$E_2$ & $(0,k_1,0)$                                 & Silla     & $(2,1)$\\
$E_3$ & $(0,k_2,0)$                                 & Silla     & $(1,2$)\\
$E_4$ & $(\frac{-\rho\tau^2-k_1\rho\tau\phi \Omega-k_2\rho\tau\phi \Omega- k_1 k_2\rho\phi^2\omega^2}{k_1k_2\phi^2\Omega^3},-\frac{\tau}{\phi\Omega},0)$        & Inestable     & $(3,0)$\\
$E_5$ & $(3.698.94, 7272.73, 672.53)$                               & Atractor & $(0,3)$\\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```